# C++ Print inputed number in ascending order using do while loop

Tags: c++

Need to display this using **do while loop** in c++ and I'm stuck with my code. This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int mn, i, n = 1;
    cout << "Enter max number: ";
    cin >> mn;

    do
    {
        cout << n << " ";
        n++;
    } while (mn >= n);
    {
        cout << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

My code only displays

```
    Enter max number: 8
    1 2 3 4 5  6 7 8
```

It supposed to display this, but I dont know how to make it work.

```
   Enter max number: 8

   1
   12
   123
   1234
   12345
   123456
   1234567
   12345678
```

Any ideas how to make it work? Thanks

Comment: Here's a great idea: 1. Take out a blank piece of paper, and a pencil. 2. Write down, in plain English, using short, logical sentences, your proposed algorithm for doing your homework assignment. 3. [Schedule an appointment with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). 4. Review your proposed algorithm with your rubber duck. 5. After your rubber duck agrees that your proposed algorithm will work, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++ code. Mission accomplished.

Comment: Posting nonsense like *Any ideas? Any ideas?* isn't going to get you a very good reception here. Please **do NOT** fill your post with noise and nonsense. Take the [tour] and read through the [help] pages in order to learn how this site works and how to conduct yourself here. If you can't follow those guidelines, feel free to go somewhere else to ask for help.

Answer (score 3):

According to the result you want, **there should be 2 loops in the code**. One is for the output of each line and the other is for the output of multiple lines.

So, you need to realize that the variable `n` in your code is just for the output of one line. You need to add an additional loop in the `do while` loop, and let n be a counter to determine how many lines the program should output.

According the result you want, I modify some `cout` codes personally. It passed test in my computer. Undoubtedly you can use `for` or `while` for the loop since these loops can represent each other mutually.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int mn,n = 1;
    cout << "Enter max number: ";
    cin >> mn;
    cout << endl;

    do
    {
        int temp = 1;
        do {
            cout << temp;
            temp++;
        }  while (n >= temp);
        cout << endl;
        n++;
    } while (mn >= n);
    return 0;
}
```